# PHP Case-Insensitive LTRIM?

Tags: php

I have an array of data I'm iterating through containing a Title and a Description. Each description currently begins with the corresponding title, so I want to ltrim() it off. Unfortunately, not all Titles were written in the same case format as used at the beginning of the description. I was going to use:

```
ltrim($description,$title)
```

but the case problem has stopped that.

Data EG:

```
array(
    array("title" => "Hello World", "description" => "Hello World This is a description"),
    array("title" => "Hellow world", "description" => "Hellow World This is a description"),
    array("title" => "Hello again", "description" => "HELLO AGAIN This is a description"));
```

ltrim($description,$title) would clean the first, but leave the others alone.

I didn't create the data I'm cleaning up btw, I've just taken over the job.

Anyway, ltrim() is case-sensitive (yes?) so I'm at abit of a loss as to how to go about this. Is there any other way of doing this?

*edit*

Forgot to mention, the Title DOESN'T ALWAYS appear in the description, just 90% of the time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ltrim is not the function you want in the first place. The second argument to ltrim is a charlist, so it will keep removing from the left of the string as long as one of the characters is encountered.

If every title is in every description you could use [str_ireplace](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php). And replace the title with nothing, and set the count to 1.

The better alternative is to use regular expressions.

```
preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote($title, '/').'\s*/i', '', $description);
```

This will replace the title if it is the first thing in the description, followed by any whitespace (so spaces/newlines will be removed if they come after the title. preg_quote is important to protect the regular expression incase the title contains any regex characters.

- [preg_replace](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- [preg_quote](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Comment: +1 much better than mine, so I deleted it in favour of yours. Hope the Regex witch hunter won't catch you :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa cheers, I do believe this is a prime use for regex, because if for some reason a title doesn't start the description, or there are multiple spaces this still works.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: since this answer has some justification with it, I'm considering not downvoting it... but the OP says the description currently begins with the title, he doesn't says "maybe yes, maybe no", so I don't know if a regexp is such a good idea.

Comment: @Jacob I think this might be the one. You've forseen an issue I forgot to mention in the original, namely: The Title doesn't Always appear in the description.

Comment: @Jacob And after testing in my case, this is the solution to my headache. Thank you very much, I would never have figured this one out

Comment: @Jacob: +1 for being visionary, I delete my answer, since it doesn't fit anymore